# Bootsnipp radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to add this bootsnipp : https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/kl7nQ
to my project, but it doesn't work.

my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="new 1.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container">         
    <div class="well well-sm text-center">
        <h3>Radio</h3>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

            <label class="btn btn-success active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" chacked>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my css page :

```
.btn span.glyphicon {               
    opacity: 0;             
}
.btn.active span.glyphicon {                
    opacity: 1;             
}
```

can you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks fine you just missed to include `bootstrap.min.js` file for the radio button to work. I've updated your code to the working one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Snippet - Touch Friendly Bootstrap Radio buttons and Checkboxes</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<style>
.btn span.glyphicon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn.active span.glyphicon {
  opacity: 1;
}

</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm text-center">
      <h3>Radio</h3>
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-success">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" checked>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```